# How do I have github ignore the three.js dependencies I have installed?

Tags: github, three.js, gitignore

So I'm a student trying to learn how to code front end of websites. I'm currently using HTML, CSS and some JS frameworks and pushing them to a github repository through VSCode. Just for practice and understanding, I installed Three.js through npm but want to ignore the node_module files through gitingore. Only thing is and I don't know how to do it in VSCode.

P.S I'm also learning react and so have managed to install Three.JS on it as it comes with it's own git ignore in the react package. I just want to know to install Three.js otherwise and have it work cause I generally don't like linking the script through a URL. It would be cool if somebody could explain to me and how git ignore generally works and if there is anything specific I have to do for the aforementioned situation

I eventually intend to upload these files to github which is connected to netlify and is hosting a static website for me on my own domain, but that's a bit far off in my plans right now

Again just here to learn because the documentation online is a bit confusing for a less coding centric student

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .gitignore file first using touch .gitignore than add the files which you want to ignore it and next time when you add this file in the folder, the files gets ignored. you can check it by using `git status` command.

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_ignoring